# Replace string which is between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having the following string `4 (10.3%)` and would like to receive `4`.

I tried:

```js
let s = "4 (10.3%)"
s.replace("/\s+\((.*?)\)", "");

console.log(s)
```

However, I still get the initial string back.

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Why cant you split the string on the whitespace and take the first part of the array?

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, it looks like you're trying to use a regular expression, in which case you should actually use a regular expression, not a string.

Comment: That's looking for the *string* `"/\s+\((.*?)\)"`. Use a regex: `/\s+\((.*?)\)/`.

Comment: @JackBashford I kindly ask you to submit a working sample for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of regex

```js
let s = "4 (10.3%)"
console.log(s.substr(0, s.indexOf(' ')))
```

Using split

```js
let s = "4 (10.3%)"
    console.log(s.split(" ")[0])
```